# React Native example from facebook.github.io/react-native/ doesn't seem to work

Tags: react-native

I used

```
react-native init AwkwardScrollingImageWithText
```

and then edited index.ios.js. However, when I run the app there is no image. It's driving me crazy as I copied/pasted their example and it's very demoralizing, I cannot make a sample work, let alone create my own apps.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

export default class AwkwardScrollingImageWithText extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
              <Image source={{uri: 'https://i.chzbgr.com/full/7345954048/h7E2C65F9/'}} />
              <Text>
                On iOS, a React Native ScrollView uses a native UIScrollView.
                On Android, it uses a native ScrollView.

                On iOS, a React Native Image uses a native UIImageView.
                On Android, it uses a native ImageView.

                React Native wraps the fundamental native components, giving you
                the performance of a native app, plus the clean design of React.
              </Text>
            </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwkwardScrollingImageWithText', () => AwkwardScrollingImageWithText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Image
  source={{ url: 'https://i.chzbgr.com/full/7345954048/h7E2C65F9/' }}
  style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
/>
```

You will have to style it in some way to make it appear.

Comment: Thank you, the text was pushed down now but the image still doesn't show up.

Comment: I tested this and it worked for me. Are you running this in a simulator? Make sure the device/simulator has internet access.

Comment: Yes, in a simulator launched with {react-native run-ios}, How can I make sure the simulator has internet access?

Comment: Ideally, it should use your computer's network. You can go to the Home screen (Cmnd + Shift + H) and test with Safari app to make sure.

Comment: Don't know why then. Anyway try giving 'uri' instead of 'url'

Comment: Also try some image that is not https

Answer (score 0):

It works with me like this:

*Apple forces us to use https and I tried it with a different image.*

*Also, you would need to use the image dimensions as @Saleel said*

```js
    <Image
      source={{ url: 'https://i.giphy.com/JltOMwYmi0VrO.gif' }}
      style={{
        width: 375,
        height: 402,
      }}
    />
```